# build poll system with Repeater control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, repeater

I want to build a poll system in asp.net with Repeater control, in DB has 2 table (Polls, PollItems). and use this code for select poll:

```
var lstPoll = (from P in Conn.Polls.ToList()
                            orderby P.PollOrder
                            select new { P.Question, P.PollID, P.PollItems }).ToList();

RepeaterPoll.DataSource = lstPoll.ToList();
RepeaterPoll.DataBind();
```

PollItems table (P.PollItems) has *PollItemID*, *PollAnswer* parametr.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterPoll" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("Question")%>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblItemPoll" runat="server" DataValueField='<%# Eval("PollItemID")%>' DataTextField='<%# Eval("PollAnswer")%>'></asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

but not Eval PollAnswer and PollItemID to rblItemPoll.

plase help me for build poll system.

Comment: Where are properties `PollItemID` and `PollAnswer` in your dataset?  You are selecting `new { P.Question, P.PollID, P.PollItems }`..

Comment: pollItems is table, and has PollItemID , PollAnswer ,...

Comment: Where is the data source for `RadioButtonList`?

Comment: thx. please give me Example for multiple polls.

Comment: I do not know how to connect to RadioButtonList data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**1 - Define your `Repeater` with the `RadioButtonList` control and specifying an `OnItemDataBound` event handler:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterPoll" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterPoll_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Question")%>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblItemPoll" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**2- Implement your logic of DataBinding the `RadioButtonList` on the `OnItemDataBound` event:**

```
protected void RepeaterPoll_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        dynamic item = e.Item.DataItem;
        RadioButtonList list = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblItemPoll");
        list.DataValueField = "PollItemId";
        list.DataTextField = "PollItemDescription";
        list.DataSource = item.PollItems;
        list.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You can define both `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` properties directly on the `RadioButtonList` tag tho.

Additionally, i retrieved the `DataItem` as `dynamic` because you are creating an anonymous type for your LINQ query result.